# i18next not working - i18n not defined

Tags: cordova, zepto, i18next

Thanks for reading. I've just got myself extremely confused while trying to add i18next into my first phonegap application. I'm very sure that I'm doing something dumb as I'm a new developer. I'd really like this to be able to work in browser (at least during development) and on device.

At the moment I'm getting the error i18n not defined on the init line

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Auth Demo 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/zepto.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/i18next.amd.withJQuery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/lib/i18next.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/index.js"></script> 
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        } else {
            onDeviceReady();
        }
        language_complete = navigator.language.split("-");
        language = (language_complete[0]);
        i18n.init({ lng: language }, function() {
            // save to use translation function as resources are fetched
            $("#content-div").i18n();
        });
    }); 
    function onDeviceReady() {
        startupBehavior(); 
    }   
    </script>
    <div id="appPage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Auth Demo</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content-div" data-role="content">
            <h2>Auth demo</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Auth demo</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js (partial)

```
function startupBehavior() {
    $("#content-div").children().remove(); //clear the form out
    $("#content-div").append('<form id="auth_login_form">');
    $("#content-div").append('<label for="Email" data-i18n="site.email"></label>');
    $("#content-div").append('<input type="text" id="auth_login_email" value="" data-i18n="site.email" placeholder="Email Address old" />');
    $("#content-div").append('<input type="button" id="auth_login_submit" onClick="handleLogin()">Log me in</input>');
$("#content-div").append('</form>');
}
```

My only ideas are that i18next doesn't work with zepto or that I might need to use require.js which I've seen mentioned a few times, but wasn't sure if that was only necessary for node.js based stuff, which this is not.

Comment: So changing from the .amd.withJQuery. version of i18next to the standard version gets me further along. But when i try to init i18next I get the error: NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
file:///Users/joe/Documents/Eclipse-Android-Workspace/authmongophonegap/assets/www/js/lib/zepto.js
Line 1360

Comment: Not sure if you're still having the issue, but are you testing this in the browser or on a phone? If in a browser (and it's Safari or Chrome), test it in Firefox.